# How can I retrieve the li tag of an unordered list and put these tags into an array using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, jquery-traversing

I am pretty new in JQuery and I have the following problem.

Into a page I have the following **unordered list**:

```
<ul id="menu-language" class="nav">
    <li id="menu-item-422" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-422">
        <a href="http://localhost/onyx/prova/">prova cat</a>
    </li>

    <li id="menu-item-185" class="qtranxs-lang-menu qtranxs-lang-menu-it menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-185">
        ..............................
        SOMETHING
        ..............................
    </li>
</ul>
```

I need to create a JQuery script that retrieve all the **li** tag (and the related HTML content of these tags) and that put it into something like an array (so each position of this array have to contain a **li** tag and its HTML content).

What is the smarter way to do it using JQuery?

Tnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$('#menu-language > li')` will return an array of li nodes, you can get the content of each li element by iterating:

```
$('#menu-language > li').each(function() {
console.log($(this).html());
});
```

Comment: Tnx, it seems to work (I replaced the console.log with an alert(), where exactly print the console.log?)

Comment: Click F12 in chrome, and then choose console or just use Ctrl + Shift + J.